# How to give assertion in soapui for rest API testing?

Tags: rest, soapui, ready-api

[image]

In the below picture, I have given assertion value as it is(Used response) ..it is working.

Whereas how to use "data" for assertion here...I tried in the same way but i got failed response.

Please help me out some one.

Comment: Can you post the json string instead of image?

Comment: What is the expected output? are you looking for `userId` value i.e., 65? or just **JsonPath Count** of `data`? If `data` count, then have you tried `$.response.data` ?

Comment: {
   "task": "userLogin",
   "response":    {
      "code": 0,
      "status": "success",
      "error_message": "",
      "success_message": "",
      "data":       {
         "userId": "65",
         "username": "indian",
         "email": "test@gmail.com",
         "token": "b0aef6139ffdc1041e01f7587a0dcf61",
         "userType": "trial",
         "profile_picture": "test.png"
      }
   }
}

Comment: Failure response:{
   "task": "userLogin",
   "response":    {
      "code": 1,
      "status": "error",
      "error_message": "invalid userid or password",
      "success_message": "",
      "data": ""
   }
}

Comment: You have provided two responses. But you have not mentioned what you wanted to verify?

Comment: Rao, please tell me how to handle assertion property content according to the above responses.....

Comment: Ok fine....now I wants to check whether "data" displaying or not? if i give right credentials details are displayed as i mentioned 1st response......If i give wrong credentials details are not displayed as i mentioned 2nd response

Comment: in JASON path expression  i give $.response.data ....then I give 1 what would be happened if 0 what would be happened.Please explain it how?

Comment: I believe groovy script suits better in your case as you wanted to verify the response contents conditionally.

Comment: Please edit your question and all full details there instead of comments.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried parsing response in script assertion and asserting

```
 import groovy.json.JsonSlurper 
def response = messageExchange.response.responseContent
def slurper = new JsonSlurper()
def json = slurper.parseText(response)
assert json.response.data!=null
```